# "Basic idea is" or "Basic ideas are"

Tags: lists, descriptive-grammar

Not sure how to adequately describe a process. Say I want to describe how to bake a cake. Which would be a better fit?

`The basic idea of making a cake is to mix up the batter, put the batter in a pan, and bake the cake until done.`

or

`The basic ideas of making a cake are to mix up the batter, put the batter in a pan, and bake the cake until done.`

I am also toying with using `The basic process of making a cake is/are...`, using `process` instead of `idea`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The basic idea of making a cake...` (singular idea) seems to flow better, and would also apply for `the basic process of making a cake`.

The steps you list are subunits of the singular idea or process. On the other hand, this can also work:

`The basic steps of making a cake are to mix up the batter, put the batter in a pan, and bake the cake until done.`

Comment: Just to be clear, you're suggesting to use `basic steps...` when there are multiple ideas, and `basic idea or process` when there is a singular idea?

Comment: I gave the example of `basic steps...` because it seemed that the continuation of your sentence listed the (multiple) _steps_ of making a cake. Together, these comprise a single idea/process.